# Am I OK to replace motherboard and add new RAID card with this RAID setup?

Tags: debian, motherboard, raid, software-raid, raid-10

This post here:

[New motherboard or new PC to gain access to RAID drives](https://superuser.com/questions/208671/new-motherboard-or-new-pc-to-gain-access-to-raid-drives/208679#208679)

Suggests that if I am using a software raid, I can swap out the motherboard with no issue as long as I am using the same OS.

This post here Defines how to detect whether or not your raid is software raid or not:
http://michaelsanford.com/how-can-i-tell-if-im-using-hardware-or-software-raid/

Which I have:

[image: Raid Setup]

I believe I should be safe to install the new motherboard and raid card (New motherboard lacks enough sata ports) due to it being a software raid, I just wanted to clarify before attempting due to the nature of the raid being a nas raid.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague and it is unclear if you have A) FakeRaid (uses motherboard's BIOS to setup RAID) or B) Linux's own software RAID and whether you're trying to replace it with A) Hardware RAID card, B) FakeRAID card or C) just transfer the disks and trust Linux's own software RAID will continue working. If you're buying an actual hardware RAID card the transfer from software RAID, be it FakeRAID or Linux RAID, probably won't work. Edit: reason I'm asking is because, if my memory serves me right, you can see FakeRAID disks with mdadm. Have you checked your (RAID)BIOS on boot?

Comment: I am using openmediasever's raid setup (which is running a debian distro). I'm unsure as to whether this is FakeRaid or Linux raid, is there a command to determine this ?

Comment: I am trying to just move it from one motherboard to the other, raid unchanged. I am nearly extending the ports available with a raid card.

Comment: Do you mean "OpenMediaVault"? Unless you specifically setup a FakeRAID, then it is most likely you're using the software RAID that comes with your server software. In my opinion this "hardware only change" is most likely to succeed.

Comment: I do indeed, my bad. I shall try determine if my raid is FakeRaid or not.

Comment: If it has bearing on whether you'll update your hardware, sure. If it doesn't, and you're going to change the motherboard anyway - then it has little matter in the end. ;) What matters most in the end is that you're not trying to move from Fake- or software RAID to hardware one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The raid I had was a software raid (Worked out as above). All I wished to achieve is replace the motherboard with a raid card to extend slots, not transfer to HW raid. This transferred fine as I was using the same os.